# Deploying a NodeJS > typescript project to azure using the Azure App Service extension in VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure

I am trying to deploy a nodeJS, typescript project to an azure deployment slot using the VSCode extension `Azure APP Service`, but i am getting the following error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory`

my project tree

[image]

my package.json

```
  {
  "name": "otj_server_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build_typescript": "tsc",
    "build_local": "cp config/config_local.json config/config.json",
    "build_dev": "cp config/config_dev.json config/config.json",
    "build_sit": "cp config/config_sit.json config/config.json",
    "build_prod": "cp config/config_prod.json config/config.json",
    "start": "tsc && nodemon build/src/index.js",
    "clean": "rimraf build",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "formidable": "^2.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "infosysta-typescript-core": "git+ssh://git@scm.infosysta.com:7999/ac/infosysta-typescript-core.git",
    "oauth": "^0.10.0",
    "random-string": "^0.2.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

The issue

[image]

What i tried

- I tried to delete the `node_modules` folder, `package-lock.json` run `npm install` and try again but with no luck
- Also I tried to force removing cache `npm cache clean --force` and do step 1 again but also with no luck

what may be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

> INFO: "ENOENT: no such file or directory"

This usually indicates that the file or directory that the application is trying to access does not exist. This could be because of incorrect file paths or any missing packages or the file is missing in the deployment slot.

Check if below troubleshooting steps helps you to fix the issue.

- Verify if the file paths in the code are valid to access files and directories and check if the file or directory exists in the path in which the application is trying to access.
- Validate if all the required packages are installed by running `npm install` in the root directory of your project.
- Check details of the error in Diagnose and solve problems:
  [image]

> - I tried to delete the  `node_modules`  folder,  `package-lock.json`  run  `npm install`  and try again but with no luck
>   Also I tried to force removing cache  `npm cache clean --force`  and do step 1 again but also with no luck

- Try out below commands:

```js
npm install
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g npm
npm install
```

After this delete `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file, and then run `npm install`.

- If none of these step's work, try creating a new deployment slot and deploying your application to the new slot. This can sometimes help to resolve issues with the deployment process.
- If you are deploying Typescript Azure function, I suggest to you prefer deploying to function app rather than web app. I was also getting the same error when I tried to deploy my function to Azure web app service.

### [image]

*I have created and deployed a project to Azure web App service from VS code.*
[image]

*The application is deployed and running in Deployment slots:*
[image]
**Result:**
[image]